# assign to matrix index pairs that are mapped to values

Tags: matlab, indexing

I've seen some post for assigning index vector to matrix, 
but what i am looking for is for the case like this:
i'm taking random values from 1:8, 
each value correspond to pair of index e.g:

```
1- [1,3]
2- [1,4]
3- [1,5]
4- [2,4]
5- [2,5]
6- [3,5]
7- [1,2]
8- [2,3]
```

then i have [5Xm] matrix of ones and i want to assign zeros according to the random values.

e.g 
random values : 1,5,2

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
%// Data
pairs = [
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 4
2 5
3 5
1 2
2 3 ];
m = 3;
values = [1 5 2];

%// Generate matrix
matrix = ones(5,m);
matrix(sub2ind(size(matrix),pairs(values,:).',repmat(1:m,size(pairs,2),1))) = 0;
```

Comment: You just explained my question, thanks! I think the OP's question needs to be clarified. The goal wasn't obvious at all.

Comment: @chappjc In fact I posted a comment requesting clarification. But then I got it, and deleted the comment. I agree, it wasn't obvious